# Foreman auto restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

In my production server, I'm using ruby foreman to run multiple processes, I just want my application to keep working, even if one of the processes down,  I want my processes to keep working even if one down , is there any tricky way to restart the process or even not to stop all the processes in case one went down ? I mean in production level I want the solution to be stable enough, is that possible without Upstart ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using foreman itself for production - it is only intended as a development tool. Instead, you can use something like [god](http://godrb.com/) with my [foreman_god](https://github.com/embarkmobile/foreman_god) gem in production.

Alternatively, you can use foreman to export config files for other process monitoring systems, for example upstart.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor your foreman process with another program like http://mmonit.com/monit/. But somehow you'll find that monitoring a process which monitor other processes is kinda strange.

Comment: isn't there any other way to do that by foreman ? and any other alternative if I can't do it with foreman ? thnx